# Deserialize Complex JSon from external JSON File

Tags: json, nested, json.net

I am new to JSON and trying to figure out stuff. I was able to deserialize a simple JSON Object/array, but when the JSON Object has nested JSON, it is failing with following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Jobject to
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

P.S: I don't know the JSON structure that is passed to the .NET program, so I had Deserialize JSON and assigned it to a dynamic .NET object. Something like

```
dynamic test = JsonConvert.Deserialize<object>(json);
```

and looped through the test object and then assigned it to `Dictionary<string,Object>` item

Any tips or suggestions to resolve Deserialization for nested JSON ??

Comment: You should also post the JSON string.

Comment: {
 "Students": [

  {
   "Name": "Amit Goenka",
   "Major": "Physics"
  }, {
   "Name": "Smita Pallod",
   "Major": "Chemistry"
  }, {
   "Name": "Rajeev Sen",
   "Major": "Mathematics"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: Sample Json string is defined above

Answer (score 0):

You need some classes representing your JSON structure:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Major { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize your JSON to an object of the RootObject:

```
var students = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```